# Physical camera as virtual camera to stream a prerecorded video

Tags: video, streaming, camera

I have a cam with a SD card (AKASO EK7000) and my goal is to stream a prerecorded video, stored in the SD card, so that, when I select the cam, I can see that video. So it's like the physical cam becomes a virtual cam.

How can I do it?

Comment: Unless your camera supports streaming video it has stored, you're out of luck. And I'm not aware of any cameras that can stream video from storage as if it came from the camera. When you connect your camera to your computer there are probably actually multiple devices connecting: The camera, for control or streaming, and the storage device, as a storage device. These are not the same device and so cannot pretend to be each other.